# How to use two properties from an entity (fields of a table) as inner key when using entity framework join method

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, linq

I have an entity that contains two properties that can be used as a key for another table,
there are two **Id**s that can be used as a **foreign key** for my **Users** table,
when I'm using **Join** method, how can i give these two as the key?
code example:

```
Join(UserRepository.Query(),
                    class => class.TeacherId || class.StudentId,
                    users=>users.Id,
                    (class, users)=> new
                    {
                        Class = class,
                        Users = users
                    });
```

using || operator did not help at all :)

Comment: Is it an option to split the query to a teacher query and a student query and then union the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` for performing such join.

```cs
var query = ClassRepository.Query()
    .SelectMany(class => UserRepository.Query()
        .Where(users => class.TeacherId == users.Id || class.StudentId == users.Id),
        (class, users) => new
        {
            Class = class,
            Users = users
        });
```

Or in Query syntax, which I prefer when it is needed to work with several tables

```cs
var query = 
    from class in ClassRepository.Query()
    from users in UserRepository.Query()
        .Where(users => class.TeacherId == users.Id || class.StudentId == users.Id)
    select new 
    {
        Class = class,
        Users = users
    };
```